# How can I update my database from my controller for values already listed in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My application is fetching stock data from Yahoo Finance and storing it into a database. Whenever I look up a new stock, I can successfully add it to the database, but I am having trouble editing existing entries. MSFT for example, is already in the database.

Here is my controller:

```
// GET: StockInfo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string csvData;
        string symbols = "MSFT";
        using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
        {
            csvData = web.DownloadString("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes/csv?s=" + symbols + "&f=sa2l1t8c1p2j1rye");
            StockInfo stocks = YahooFinance.Parse(csvData); // Place fetched data into model properties

            // Check if in database
            StockInfo temp = db.StockInfo.Find(stocks.Symbol);

            if (temp == null) // Create new entry
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.StockInfo.Add(stocks);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else // Edit Existing Entry
            {
                // not done yet
            }
        }
        return View(db.StockInfo.ToList());
    }
```

And here is my model:

```
public class StockInfo
{
    [Key]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    public decimal AverageVolume { get; set; }

    public decimal LastTradePrice { get; set; }

    public decimal OneYearTarget { get; set; }

    public decimal Change { get; set; }

    public String ChangePercent { get; set; }

    public String MarketCap { get; set; }

    public decimal PriceEarningsRatio { get; set; }

    public String DividendYield { get; set; }

    public decimal EarningsPerShare { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried other solutions on stack overflow involving entity state but they don't seem to be working for me. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Why do you have `if (ModelState.IsValid)` there?  You are not passing in any models into the controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
else // Edit Existing Entry
{
    // update temp fields here from stocks values
    temp.AverageVolume = stocks.AverageVolume;
    temp.LastTradePrice = stocks.LastTradePrice;
    temp.OneYearTarget = stocks.OneYearTarget;
    temp.Change = stocks.Change;
    temp.ChangePercent = stocks.ChangePercent;
    temp.MarketCap = stocks.MarketCap;
    temp.PriceEarningsRatio = stocks.PriceEarningsRatio;
    temp.DividendYield = stocks.DividendYield;
    temp.EarningsPerShare = stocks.EarningsPerShare;

    db.Entry(temp).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```